# CMake WORLD_WRITE permission isn't applied on INSTALL

Tags: cmake, installation

I install an empty directory from a `CMakeLists.txt` by doing the following:

```
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/var/log)

install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/var
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
        DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS
          OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ OWNER_EXECUTE
          GROUP_WRITE GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE
          WORLD_WRITE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE
        COMPONENT runtime
       )
```

I expect to see these permissions:

```
/opt/myapp $ ls -l
drwxrwxrwx root root var
drwxrwxrwx root root var/log
```

but instead I see:

```
/opt/myapp $ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x root root var
drwxrwxrwx root root var/log
```

`DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS` `WORLD_WRITE` and `GROUP_WRITE` are applied to `var/log` but not `var`.  Currently I need to `sudo chmod 777 var` to get my program to run.  How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after I couldn't reproduce it with a MCVE.

One CMakeLists.txt which was included with `add_subdirectory()` contained:

```
install(DIRECTORY var DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} COMPONENT runtime)
```

That over-wrote the permissions of the `install` command from the higher-level `CMakeLists.txt`